# Suitable AD Structure - Users by Org, Devices by Network?

Tags: active-directory

I am working on my first AD structure design and I have read quite a few documents on best practices and most of them say to build users by company org and devices as they would pertain to GP. Our company is like a small city of departments with vastly different function, while at the same time we have segregated networks for computer function.

My question is if this design is what most of you would consider falls into best practice, or should certain elements be more generalized like `servers` at a higher level. I think we have the OU's themselves figured out, just unsure exactly at what hierarchy level they should fall.

- domain.com

  - CCTV Network

    - Servers
    - Viewing Clients
    - Cameras
  - Corp Network

    - Mac Clients

      - Desktops
      - Laptops
    - PC Clients

      - Security Terminals
      - Accounting
    - Servers
  - POS Network

    - Ticketing Terminals
    - Food Service Terminals
    - Cash Handling Terminals
    - Servers
  - Staff

    - Executive
    - Finance & Accounting
    - Marketing & Sales
    - Food Service
    - Human Resources
    - Maintenance & Development
    - Risk Management
    - Security
    - First Aid
    - Wardrobe
    - Properties
    - Motel Operations

Also, should these OU's be at the top level under the domain, or should I create a single OU to hold the networks and staff in? I've read not to use the default `computers` and `users` containers in the domain root.

Answer (score 3):

Your staff OU looks good, but you may want to put it inside an OU called users.  this way you can have:

- ou=users

  - ou=staff
  - ou=contractors
  - ou=service-accounts

but this is all personal preference.

for your hardware, you might want to consider grouping by type, so:

- ou=servers

  - ou=cctv
- ou=client-machines

  - ou=pc

    - ou=accounting
  - ou=mac

    - ou=desktop
    - ou=laptop
  - ou=security

    - ou=cctv-cameras
    - ou=cctv-terminals

All of this is personal preference though.  It is also said that you will always hate your first deployment.  If you can, try to do some smaller scale lab testing with your tree and see how it works and how it feels to you.

Comment: That is really helpful. I do like the idea of breaking out the servers at the first level so that global server GP could be applied to all. I also hadn't even thought about contractors and service-accounts!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend having a Computers and a User root OU.  You can then use these for pinning Group Policy to.  Under here, divide up based on whatever makes sense for you.  One suggestion though, and this depends on the nature of your company... some folks get carried away with mapping the organisational structure into AD.  This may be fine, and, let's not forget that OU stands for Organisational Unit, but, in my experience, organisational structures change, and can change frequently.  However, if you are using AD OUs to make management of your domain easier, I'd seriously consider splitting things in a more IT-centric way.  For example:

```
ou=Corp Computers
   ou=Servers
       ou=CCTV
       ou=Exchange
       ou=File Servers
       ou=xxxxx
   ou=Client Machines
       ou=MAC
           ou=Laptops
           ou=Desktops
       ou=PC
           ou=xxxxx
ou=Corp Users   
    ou = Normal Users
    ou = Contractors
    ou = Application
    ou = Elevated Privileges
```

In short, use OUs to make your life easier, and don't forget that their true power comes into effect once you get your Group Policy settings in place.

Comment: Yup - IME, OUs are primarily used for LDAP filtering (Exchange dynamic distribution lists, etc) and for assigning GPOs. If your user or PC GPOs are few in number and apply to most/all targets, don't go nuts with dozens of OUs.